# How to get the current working directory(current working folder) name instead of the path name?

Tags: c++, c, linux, path

I know how to get **CWD**'s path name through the `getcwd` function , and I'm using the `strtok` function to get the **directory name(means current working folder)** , is there anything available to get this thing through a simple query or a function?

Comment: `getcwd` gives a directory path already. Are you looking for [realpath(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html) ?

Comment: Use basename as suggested in answer below to get only the directory name(without path),i.e for 
`/usr/bin/sort` , basename will return you sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `getcwd()` returns `"/this/is/my/cwd"` and you want just `"cwd"` then you might like to use [`basename()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/basename.3.html) on what was returned by `getcwd()`.

```
#include <unistd.h> /* for getcwd() */
#include <libgen.h> /* for basename() */

[...]

  char cwd[PATH_MAX] = "";
  char * cwd_base = NULL;

  if (NULL == getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)))
  {
    perror("getcwd() failed");
  }
  else
  {
    cwd_base = basename(cwd);
  }

  if (NULL != cwd_base)
  {
    printf("The current working directory's base name is '%s'.\n", cwd_base);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`strrchr()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strrchr) using the platform's directory separator, not `strtok()`.

Of course, "current working folder" typically needs to be a full absolute path in order to be useful for file-system access.

Answer (score 0):

Use whatever comes handy:

- strtok
- strrchr
- or even a regular expression library, like http://www.pcre.org/

For this particular case, all of those are sufficiently easy to use. And if you use such a lot, factor it out into a "helper" subroutine.